# Perl Datetime subtraction problem

Tags: perl, datetime, date, subtraction

I've got a little problem by subtracting two datetime objects from each other. I use the following code:

```
    $today = DateTime->now( time_zone => 'Europe/Berlin' );

    my $dt1 = DateTime-> new (
                     year => 2011,
                     month => 08,
                     day   => 08,
                     hour => 1,
                     minute => 0,
                     second => 4,
                     time_zone =>'Europe/Berlin'
                     );

    print "DT1 : $dt1\n";
    print "today: $today\n";

    my $sub = $today->subtract_datetime($dt1);

    print "sub days: ".$sub->days."\n";
```

The print statement for DT1 and today prints:

```
DT1 : 2011-08-08T01:00:04
today: 2011-08-16T08:34:10
```

But if I print after the subtraction the `$sub->days` value it shows **1** instead of **8** days.

Do I have a error in my subtraction?

Many thanks for your help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `DateTime::Duration` does not work as you (and I) expected. Check all fields of `$sub`:

```
DT1 : 2011-08-08T01:00:04
today: 2011-08-16T09:02:11
$sub->years: 0
$sub->months: 0
$sub->weeks: 1
$sub->days: 1
$sub->hours: 8
$sub->minutes: 2
$sub->seconds: 7
```

The difference between the two dates is **1 week + 1 day**, the expected eight days.

If you want the difference in days, try `$today->delta_days( $dt1 )`. The delta_days() method returns a duration which contains only days *(edit) and weeks, but not months.*

Comment: Not quite. `delta_days` still returns weeks and days, so you still need to use `in_units`. The difference is that it won't return months, which can't be converted to days.

Comment: I've solved it via an if clause to check it: if $sub->weeks > 0 then $days = $sub->weeks * 7 + $sub->days

Comment: just use as @ikegami suggested $sub->in_units('days'), otherwise your solution will work as soon the duration is no more than a month

Answer (score 0):

The resulting duration is of 1 week and 1 day. Weeks can be safely converted to days, so you can get the desired result using

```
$dur->in_units('days')
```

Keep in mind that months cannot be converted into days, and subtraction can produce durations with months. As such, you really want to use

```
my $dur = $today->delta_days($dt1);
print "sub days: ".$dur->in_units('days')."\n";
```

---

PS — 08 is an error:

```
Illegal octal digit '8' at a.pl line 7, at end of line
Illegal octal digit '8' at a.pl line 8, at end of line
```

Drop the leading zero.